# Trouble with a voltage follower

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm having trouble when I'm trying to make a voltage-follower from GL324 opamp. I use the following data sheet:

http://www.datasheet-pdf.com/PDF/GL324-Datasheet-LGSemicon-558557

And following connections:

[image]

[image]

I use 12VDC as Vcc. And above is a photo from my setup. If I apply 9V as input there is no output. If I apply reverse voltage with the 9V battery, I see minus reading from the voltmeter. And the opamp gets very hot. I double checked my wiring and it matched the circuit schematics and datasheet.

What could be wrong?

Comment: If you applied -9V from a single rail supply, you've probably fried it.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Is the schematics right? So you are saying the opamp is broken?

Comment: Schematics fine. Can't tell entirely from the picture but it looks wired up ok (unless there are loose connections). Have you probed the voltages on each pin to make sure they are correct?

Comment: yes pin one and two (2 red in photo) are connected since they are inverting input and output. yellow one is pin three and it is the signal input. Two browns are GND and Vcc for the opamp. I checked many times. the jumper brown is output to the voltmeter.

Comment: I can roughly see that, but have you probed each pin with the multimeter to check it is at the expected voltage - e.g. to detect broken wires, etc. I'd also try a different amplifier (there are 4 in the IC, so try one of the other 3).

Comment: i checked the wiring several times

Comment: tried wired the second amplifier in the same IC; Im getting exactly same problem.. I will go crazy

Comment: @Tom Carpenter I changed the entire IC now it works. I think it was broken. I have a question though. What is the max current I can draw from the output of this opamp?

Comment: @user16307 The datasheet has a line for "output current". What does it say there?

Comment: TYP 40mA. I should use a transistor for higher than 40mA load right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been more years than I can remember since using breadboard but shouldn't the op-amp sit over the trough that runs horizontally through the middle: -

[image]

See also this to confirm: -

[image]

Ground power also needs to connect to the common connection for Vin and Vout.

Comment: I think you are right since in my second try with another lm324 I inserted it in the middle and it worked. Probably pins were loose I didnt notice in the first way. It makes sense what you say..

Comment: You are a good learner!

Comment: the main point actually the pins are in the same line was totally wrong as you say. strange that no one noticed besides you.-

Comment: As you get more experienced you tend to want to question everything lol

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your signal voltages and meters are not connected to power supplies, but are completely floating. What you need to do is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffd7sV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you showed it, the measurements and signals, having no connection to any reference point common to the op amp, are never going to make sense.

Comment: 9V is my input signal Vcc is 12VDC. All grounds all connected. I dont think thats problem here.

Comment: @user16307 - Then edit your schematic to show exactly how your circuit is connected.

Comment: I wrote in my question I use 12V u draw 9V Vcc

Comment: @user16307, Your schematic shows nothing connected to the VCC and VEE pins of the op-amp. Please edit your schematic to show what you actually connected. For many of us, we can understand your circuit much more quickly by looking at your schematic than by reading your words.

Comment: @ThePhoton I used another IC now on the breadboard. Thats the only photo remained.. But I think I figured out the problem. The opamp was defect definitely. I tried with another 324 another brand it worked.